# "I" or "me" in one word question

Tags: personal-pronouns

Which of the two is more correct, when one wants to make sure whether he/she is a subject of the statement (ex. the sentence is addressed at two people, and one of those two people wants to make sure, whether the sentence is addressed at him/her).

> You have beautiful eyes.
>
> Me?

or

> You have beautiful eyes.
>
> I?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You have the wrong dupe. “Who, me?”  Yes, you.

Comment: tchrist Are you saying that the following (by Daniel) doesn't give the answer?  <<Arnold Zwicky writing on the Language Log in a post called "Here Comes the Accusative" discusses the use of accusative pronouns ('I' is nominative and 'me' is accusative):

...the basic rule for nominative/accusative choice in English is: nominative for subjects of finite clauses, accusative otherwise.>>

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by 'when one wants to make sure whether he/she is a subject of the statement?'? Do you mean 'when one wants to make sure whether he/she is being spoken to'? 'Subject' has a specific meaning in grammar; here, the subject in both sentences is 'You'.

Comment: I've updated my question. Hope it's clear now. Btw. I don't quite consider two linked questions as possible direct duplicates...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree with Arnold.

Comment: @tchrist Hence I've got a correct duplicate (though it should probably be combined with the one you found).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A case can be made for either, but "Me?" is far more common. The reply "I?" feels stilted and artificial.

Answer (score -2):

The answer

> me?

could plausibly be interpreted as being short for either of

> Are you talking to me?
>   Are you referring to me?

whereas

> I?

could plausibly be interpreted as being short for

> Do I?

so this seems to be a case where the coin lands on its edge.